# useEffect with firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I'm trying to do the following, i cannot get any errors but what's weird is, while `setRivalGuess` in the first condition  `setRivalGuess(doc.data().guess2)` doesn't work, the second one `setRivalGuess(doc.data().guess1)` works really well.  I checked database and everything stored well, that is, each data that I want to fetch is available on the database. I don't know whether it is about my way of using `useEffect`.

```
const { rivalGuess, setRivalGuess } = useGame(); 
const game = query(roomColRef, where("roomId", "==",  roomId))
useEffect(() => {
    const getUsers = async () => {
        const data = await getDocs(game);
        data.forEach((doc)=> {
            if (doc.data().numberOfPlayers == 2 ){
                if(userValue == doc.data().players[0].username)
                    if (doc.data().guess2 =! 0){
                        setRivalGuess(doc.data().guess2)}
                if (userValue == doc.data().players[1].username) 
                    if (doc.data().guess1 =! 0){ 
                        setRivalGuess(doc.data().guess1)} }})};
    getUsers();
  }, [ rivalGuess, setRivalGuess ])
```

Comment: Using `setX()` within a loop is never really needed. If your conditions evaluate to true for multiple documents, then it will lead to your state being set multiple times which isn't useful as only the last state that you set is what is used. Instead you should use the loop to find the value you want, and then use `setRivalGuess()` outside of your loop. You should check that you're not overwriting the `setRivalGuess(doc.data().guess2)` state in a subsequent iteration of your loop.

Comment: `rivalGuess` also doesn't appear to be referenced inside the `useEffect` hook, and since the `useEffect` hook updates the `rivalGuess` state you probably don't want it in the dependency array anyway.

Comment: actually doing so causes not to update rivalGuess in anyway ;
im using rivalGuess  on the game page to show each rival's move ...  `<ol> { rivalGuess.map(( e, index ) => ( <li  key= { index } > 
                         
                                { e.guess } + { e.bulls } - { e.cows } </li> ))} </ol>`

Comment: Could you try to remove the second `setRivalGuess` that works as you stated and check if it will give you your expected result in `setRivalGuess(doc.data().guess2)`. As other members said. It's probably replacing the data when you set another data to the current state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rivalGuess` was before global state , but know it's in the hook.

```
const UseRivals = (collectionStr) =>{
        const [ rivalGuess,  setRivalGuess ] =useState([])
        const { roomId, userValue } = useGame()
        useEffect(() => {
            const collectionRef = collection(db, collectionStr);
            const q = query(collectionRef, where("roomId", "==", roomId ))
            const unSub = onSnapshot(q , (snapshot) => {
                snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                if (doc.data().numberOfPlayers==2) {
                    if (userValue == doc.data().players[0].username) if (doc.data().guess2 =! 0) 
                     { setRivalGuess(doc.data().guess2) }
                    if  (userValue == doc.data().players[1].username) if  (doc.data().guess1 =! 0)
                        { setRivalGuess(doc.data().guess1)}}})
            }, (err) => {
                console.log(err.message);
            });
            return () => unSub();
        }, [collectionStr]);
    
        return { rivalGuess };
    }
    export default UseRivals;
```